# Construct jQuery selector out of multiple variables

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to make my jQuery code less repetitive by constructing a selector out of two
variables.

I would like to put the class 'legend' and the second classname in two separate variables
and combine them as one selector.

My HTML

```
 <div class="legend a">
    <div class="icon"></div>
        <p class="description">Autmotive</p>
    <div class="switch"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="legend b">
    <div class="icon"></div>
        <p class="description">Power Conversion</p>
    <div class="switch"></div>  
 </div>
 <div class="legend c">
    <div class="icon"></div>
        <p class="description">Charger Switches</p>
    <div class="switch"></div>
 </div>
```

My jQuery

```
$('.legend.a').hover(
  function () { $('.call-out.a').find('.icon').addClass('hover')},
  function () { $('.call-out.a').find('.icon').removeClass('hover')}
);

$('.legend.b').hover(
  function () { $('.call-out.b').find('.icon').addClass('hover')},
  function () { $('.call-out.b').find('.icon').removeClass('hover')}
);

$('.legend.c').hover(
  function () { $('.call-out.c').find('.icon').addClass('hover')},
  function () { $('.call-out.c').find('.icon').removeClass('hover')}
);
```

I tried:

```
var firstClass = $('.legend').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
var secondClass = $('.legend').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
var legend = $('.'+ firstClass +'.'+ secondClass +'');
```

But it's targeting all elements. How can I target legend.a, b or c separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a data attribute to specify the target class:

```
 <div class="legend a" data-target="a">
```

Then your js can be more generic, like:

```
$('.legend').hover(
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  function () { $('.call-out.' + target).find('.icon').addClass('hover')},
  function () { $('.call-out.' + target).find('.icon').removeClass('hover')}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about generalizing the hover function like below,

```
//  v-- Seleact all legend
$('.legend').hover(
  function () { 
     var targ  = $(this)[0].className.split(' ')[1];
     $('.call-out.' + targ).find('.icon').addClass('hover')
  },
  function () { 
     var targ  = $(this)[0].className.split(' ')[1];
     $('.call-out.' + targ).find('.icon').removeClass('hover')
  }
);
```

Comment: I think you are meaning to split on the class attribute, not the element itself

Comment: @JustinBicknell You are right.. Thanks and corrected the answer.